# Change start of screen animation

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity

I want one of my activites to come from the bottom of the screen when it starts and when it finishes I want it to dissapear back to the bottom.
Is it possible to do it? And if yes - any idea how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to change how an activity starts, but to make it close in a certain way, you can override the finish() method and add an animation.

you can call overridePendingTransition after startActivity() to change how the scene changes when you start a new activity.

```
@Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
    }
```

where slide_out_bottom comes in your Res\anim folder and could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

This is altered code from a project, so you have to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You should define two `animations`: enter and exit for your activity

**R.anim.enter**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
           android:fromYDelta="100%p"
           android:toYDelta="0%p"/>
```

**R.anim.exit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
           android:fromYDelta="0%p"
           android:toYDelta="100%p"/>
```

and use this anims in your activity

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, android.R.anim.fade_out)
    }

    override fun finish() {
        super.finish()
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.exit, android.R.anim.fade_in)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        finish()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call overridePendingTransition after startActivity() to change  start a new activity animation.

**try this line of code**

**slide_to_left.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
           android:duration="@integer/slide_animation_duration"/>
```

**slide_to_right**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
           android:duration="@integer/slide_animation_duration"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

**startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left);**